Does ARINC-664 (AFDX) supersedes both ARINC-429 and ARINC-629?
Wondering if ARINC-664 (and ARINC-629) have backwards combability with ARINC-429. I realize -664 uses Ethernet while -429 is implemented using a two-wire data bus. However, wanted to see if any of the 32-bit ARINC-429 are "ported" upwards.

The network definitions of A429, A629, and A664 are independent of each other. If you look at the OSI model, one significant difference is that A429 includes the two translation/presentation layer options. One of which is the traditional  A429 messaging and the other a block data transfer. For the A429 messaging, it also includes the standard data dictionary. A629 and A664 are more traditional data bus standards for a full-duplex interconnection. A629 is a scheduled bus network. A664 is similar to Ethernet with topology and scheduling constraints to  make it more deterministic (guaranteed delivery and maximum latency). But A629 and A664 don't specify the data that's sent across the network. Since A629 is pretty much limited to legacy B777, I'll discuss just A664 as the multipoint network going forward, though the concepts are identical. (You probably wouldn't ever see A629 and A664 on the same aircraft. A664 has effectively replaced A629 as the high bandwidth bus.)
In the real world of an aircraft "network" it is common to use use two or more network types and have data move across them all. An aircraft has many sensors that provide everything from a small data stream of a few hundred bits/sec to video streams of MBits/sec. For cost and power/weight reasons, smaller low cost busses provide low rate data to data concentrators that forward the data onto the high speed/high bandwidth bus. For example, B787 uses CAN Bus, A429, and A664.
Following the above example, The overhead control panel is connected via CAN Bus to a gateway that connects to the A664 network. The status of each of the switches on the panel is a single bit in the CAN message which gets lumped into a big data word on the A664 network. Similarly, many legacy LRUs such as the Radio Altimeter just have a couple A429 output busses with a handful of data words. The A429 busses are connected to a data concentrator that packages the A429 labels into a larger block word and forwards it across the A664 network. Data can also go the other way. For high bandwidth devices such as the weather radar, it has its own A664 interface which can easily handle the bandwidth. In the A380, the A664 network is primarily associated with the display system which has relatively high bandwidth needs.
For convenience and interchangeability most data that has to go over A429 retains the standard A429 message formats. Within the A664 network, they are just opaque data blocks. For everything else, the aircraft integrator and the suppliers all have to agree on a data structure for the aircraft. It's a lot more up front work, but it allows for changes to be incorporated via software updates where the older A429-only systems required wiring changes which added a lot to the cost of change.
